# live ads are not showing after publish app in Google Play Store

Tags: cordova, admob, android-studio-3.0, cordova-3

We developed app in Cordova and we used "Cordova-plugin-admob-free" plugin (https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free) for admob ads. it's showing google test ads perfectly. but it does not showing live ads even after published.

We also updated payment details and linked app in admob account. We also set istesting = false in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, We got solution by using basic example of "Cordova-plugin-admob-free" plugin of github. we used same java script which used in basic example.